# How to create and use Stored Procedure on MS Access (.mdb File) with VB.Net Windows Application

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

My IDE is Visual studio 2008.

I just want to ask how to create Stored Procedures in Microsoft Access Database (.mdb) and pass the values to a VB.NET Windows Application.

Thanks for the Answer.

i need to know:
  - how to create stored Procedures
  - how to connect to the database
  - how to call the stored procedure in the VB.NET Codes for windows app.
  - how to use the values in reports.

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to stored procedures in access are queries. You can follow the access help and tutorials for information on how to create one.

Once you have it created, you can access it from VB as follows:

```
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\myaccess.mdb"
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "NameOfTheQuery"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            ' Note: You can also use CommandType.TableDirect
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

The above assumes that you have the following imports statement at the top of your code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Comment: Thanks for the help competent_tech. 

Follow-up question, how to get the result of the stored procedure?

And also, what if the Stored Procedure has 3 Parameters for SELECT Statement. How will it be passed from VB.net to Stored Procedure. 

Thanks a lot.